# Using require for SVG files in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, svg

Im using [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg) and I'm fully aware of their way to use local svg files as shown [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg#use-with-svg-files).
What I would like to know is if there is a way to use `require` for svg file paths. e.g.

```
<Svg width={50} height={50} fill={"#CCC"} source={require("./path/to/file.svg")} />
```

That way I would be able to store the require in a variable and use it like:

```
const myImage = require("./path/to/file.svg")

<Svg width={50} height={50} fill={"#CCC"} source={myImage} />
```

Any ideias?

**EDIT FOR MORE DETAIL**

Im developing a white label app so I have a config.js file with some color values, API endpoints and source images. e.g.

```
//config.js
const coBrandConfig = {
  firstapp: {
    Target: {
      BRAND_TARGET: "firstApp"
    },

    Login: {
      LOGIN_BACKGROUND_IMAGE: require("./path/to/file.png"),
      LOGIN_LOGO_IMAGE: require("./path/to/file.png"),

      LOGIN_TITLE_TEXT: "FIRST APP",

      LOGIN_STATUSBAR_CONTENT: "light-content",
      LOGIN_BACKGROUND_COLOR: "#333" ,
      LOGIN_SIMPLE_TEXT_COLOR: "#FFF",
      LOGIN_TEXTINPUT_BACKGROUD_COLOR: "#FFF",
      LOGIN_LOGIN_BUTTON_COLOR: "#009933",
    },
  },
}

module.exports = coBrandConfig["firstapp"]
```

Then I have a styles.js that gets and applies all of these values, which can change depending on the App variant. e.g.

```
import React from 'react'
import { StatusBar, Image } from "react-native"
import styled from 'styled-components/native'
import CoBrandConfig from "./config/config.js"

export function MainStyle () {
  return(
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle={`${CoBrandConfig.Login.LOGIN_STATUSBAR_CONTENT}`} backgroundColor={CoBrandConfig.Login.LOGIN_BACKGROUND_COLOR} />
      <Image source={CoBrandConfig.Login.LOGIN_LOGO_IMAGE} />
      <Svg width={50} height={50} fill={"#CCC"} source={CoBrandConfig.Login.MY_SVG} /> //HERES WHAT I WANT TO DO
      <TitleText>{CoBrandConfig.Login.LOGIN_TITLE_TEXT}</TitleText>
    </>
  )
}
```

Thats why I would like to pass a `require("./path/to/file.svg")` to a variable.

Comment: You want it that way so you could change the path for another svg from the code it self?

Comment: Yes. I want to pass a couple of svg files to different variables so I can chose what variables to use on the go.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible. Because you need to import the image/svg or any file before you can use it in your app.
So you will need to import all the svgs. and then choose different one each time.
Or upload them and use different url each time. but then the app won't show it offline.

Comment: Try to import all of them. set them in array and use the array of imported svgs. good luck!

Comment: Im fine importing all of them, I already do that for png/jpgs as I showed in the code above.. I just dont know how to do that for svg, just because I cant require them and pass it to a variable

Comment: So just make it array of premade Svg and each with different path.

Comment: And if this svg are icons set. the best practice is to create font set with them.

Comment: Can you please spare some code on how to make it array of premade Svg?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late, but try adding `.default.src` after your require:

```
source={require("./path/to/file.svg").default.src}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this library, I hope it will be useful

```
npm install 'react-native-svg';
```

then

```
import { SvgUri } from 'react-native-svg';
<SvgUri
  width="100%"
  height="100%"
  uri="url svg"
  />
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
import SvgUri from 'react-native-svg-uri';
import svgExample from './file.svg';
```

return:

```
  <SvgUri
    width="250"
    height="250"
    svgXmlData={svgExample}
  />
```

Comment: Im sorry but I dont quite get how does this solves my issue.